# How to convert a String to a Float which is rounded UP to 4 decimal places

Tags: groovy

I have this string: "123,456.39213212"
I would like to to be converted to a float and rounded UP to the 4th decimal place.

According to an online tool I used I should get this number: 123456.3922

Please advise how I can do this in Groovy?

Thanks

Comment: Why not "123456.3921"? And where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: Would that not be rounding down? I used this tool and got the value I stated: https://www.browserling.com/tools/round-numbers-up. I have used this code float fCastedNumber = Float.parseFloat(strValue) but it only returns 2 decimal points and it is not rounded

Comment: Sorry, didn't read the explicit "UP". It's too late ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It feels a bit hacky, but if your thousands separator is always `,` you can do something like this:

```
import java.math.RoundingMode

def input = "123,456.39213212"
def output = new BigDecimal(input.replaceAll(",", "")).setScale(4, RoundingMode.UP)
```

​Output:

```
123456.3922
```

Key parts are:

1. Replacing the comma with `""` to have the string in a format that `BigDecimal` can work with and
2. Setting the scale to 4 using `RoundingMode.UP` (note: depending on your requirements regarding negative numbers you may want to use `RoundingMode.CEILING` instead)

Comment: Perfect! - thank you -- doesn't seem hacky to me :-)